# Creating Side by Side Barcharts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a side by side bar chart from this subset of a data frame

```
ExitVelocityAverage

 Name          CombinedAvgEV PlayerAvgEV
  <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Adam Harrison          85.9        80.8
```

Ultimately I would have one barchart that has Adam's Average (PlayerAvgEV) and another barchart that shows the total average of the data frame (CombinedAvgEV). Ideally these barcharts would be side by side and this would show that Adam is below the average.

This is where I am at but it isn't working

```
ggplot(ExitVelocityAverage, aes(x=Name))
  geom_bar(aes(x = Name,y=PlayerAvgEV), col = "red", fill = "red", stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Name,y=CombinedAvgEV), col = "blue", fill = "blue", stat="identity")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: e.g. `ggplot(ExitVelocityAverage) + geom_col(aes(Name, PlayerAvgEV)) + geom_col(aes('League average', CombinedAvgEV))`

Comment: Can only guess without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but you probably need to reshape your data into the long format that ggplot expects to work with, then use a variable for setting color

Comment: Thank you so much!!